# Определить тип

Tags: python, python-3.x

подскажите пожалуйста почему этот код выводит тип str для каждого элемента словаря db

```
db = dict()
db['id'] = 1
db['type'] = 'abc'
db['video'] = ['zcxz', 'asd', 'qwe']
keys = ['id', 'type', 'video']

for item in db:
    print(item, '--', db[item], 'type is: ', type(item))
```

ведь `['zcxz', 'asd', 'qwe']` это не строка а список(!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что item это строка - ключ кортежа, Вам нужно выводить не

```
type( item )
```

а

```
type( db[item] )
```

Python для списков и массивов перебирает их значения:

```
print( [i for i in (5,6) ] ) # [5, 6]
print( [i for i in [5,6] ] ) # [5, 6]
```

Для кортежей - ключи:

```
print( [i for i in {1:5,2:6} ] ) # [1, 2]
```

Comment: Добавлю чуть-чуть: в случае обнаружения такой wtf-ситуации (с опытом они уйдут, кстати) первым делом нужно проверить входные значения (в нашем случае тот самый item), в 90% случаев ответ найдется прямо в них.